# Cube appearing around mesh in Object Mode, but not Edit Mode

Tags: objects, edit-mode, mirror, mirror-modifier

I have this strange cube that doesn't appear while I'm in edit mode. The mesh has a mirror modifier attached to it, but even if I apply it the cube remains. What am I missing here?

[image]
CUBE

[image]
No CUBE

Comment: What happens if you hit ALT-H (unhide all) when you're in Edit mode, and can you select it when you're in Object mode? If you can select it (yellow outline), does it hilight as an extra object in the Outliner and can you delete it? If none of that works, you'll have to share the file so that someone can have a look. - https://blend-exchange.com/help

Comment: I feel like a fool, ALT-H did it. Guess I accidentally hid the default cube. Thanks for the help!

Comment: That may be why quite a few tutorials seem to start by deleting the default cube and immediately adding another one nowadays! Mind you, why you actually hid it when in Edit mode is a bit of a mystery! :^))

Answer (score 0):

I think it's hidden, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> in edit mode and then delete the cube, that will solve the problem.